# what is the main difference between .net Async and google go light weight thread

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, go, .net-4.5

When calling runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1) in go the runtime will only use one thread for all your goroutines. When doing io your goroutines will yield and let the other goroutines run on the same thread.

This seem very similar to me to how the .net Async CTP feature is doing cooperative concurrency if you are not using background thread.

My question is which advantage or drawback could you think of one methode over the other.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Making value judgements is always a tricky thing so I'll highlight 3 differences. You decide whether they fall into the "pro" or "con" bucket.

1. While both Go and async allow you to write async code in a straightforward way, in .NET you have to be aware which part of your code is async and which one isn't (i.e. you have to explicitly use async/await keywords). In Go you don't need to know that - the runtime makes it "just work", there is no special syntax to mark async code.
2. Go design doesn't require any special code in standard library. .NET required adding new code to the standard library for every async operation, essentially doubling API surface for those cases e.g. there's new async http download API and the old, non-async http download API has to remain for backwards compatibility.
3. Go design and implementation is orders of magnitude simpler. A small piece of runtime code (scheduler) takes care of suspending goroutines that block on system calls and yielding to sleeping goroutines. There is no need for any special async support in standard library.

.NET implementation first required adding the aforementioned new APIs. Furthermore .NET implementation is based on compiler rewriting code with async/await into an equivalent state machines. It's very clever but also rather complicated. The practical result was that the first async CTP had known bugs while Go's implementation was working pretty much from the beginning.

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter. async/await is the best way to write async code in .NET. Goroutines are the best way to get that in Go. Both are great, especially compared to alternatives in most other languages.

Comment: Really great answer thank you. I was more thinking in term of execution speed performance for some one that need to choose between the 2 language.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. You can write go-style goroutines in C# and Java, by using thread-per-process (channels are simply synchronous queues). In many the cases, you don't care about the fact that in Go goroutines are multiplexed across a handful of OS threads. C# async promises you that certain code will run in the same OS thread, which is very good for the case of the UI thread. You can't get such a promise with go.

Comment: Can sombody provide an example how await would be simulated in Go? As far as I know, there is no such thing.

Comment: @Elazar: for the specific case of ensuring running on UI thread, you use LockOSThread() in Go (http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/LockOSThread). Without going into too much detail, your comment is misleading. You want the body of await statement to run on non-UI thread so that long computation or blocking on IO doesn't also block UI thread. Sometimes you have to run the remainder of the code on UI thread because of thread safety concerns. await makes such code easy to write. In Go you get the same thing with go statement and you coordinate the UI thread work with messages on channels.

Comment: @Kugel: it doesn't make sense to have await/async in Go just as it doesn't make sense to have Go's go statement in C#. Those are both language level features that require support from the compiler and runtime. Neither language is flexible enough to replicate such fundamental designs from the other language. They don't have to be. async/await is a C# solution to writing sane concurrent code. Goroutines are Go's solution to the same problem. Use the best solution that a given language gives you instead of looking for exact replica of a solution from another language.

Comment: @KrzysztofKowalczyk: My last statement was to harsh. I should've say "it's hard to do that with go". From the LockOSThread wiki: "Go's runtime provides LockOSThread() function for this, but it's notoriously difficult to use correctly". Go manages OS threads behind your back, so it's hard to control which function runs where. Usually it's a good idea, but sometimes you care about which OS threads runs what. I don't understand what's misleading about my comment. To my understanding C#'await is like running a set of goroutines on 1 thread. You can't get that easily in Go. http://bit.ly/13mxBG5

Comment: @KrzysztofKowalczyk I understand that both models are different, what I'm looking for in go is sort of continuation that await provides on the original thread.

Comment: Relevant: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/